# Mvvmcross Bind Click triggered only after focus

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

```
    <CC.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/receptionIdentityArticle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ExtendProTheme"
        android:maxLength="20"
        style="@style/ExtendProTheme.EditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/suppliersSearchInputLabel"
        local:MvxBind=" Text ArticleSearchClause, Mode=TwoWay; EnterCommand SearchArticlesCommand; Error Errors['ArticleSearchClause']; Click OnSearchClickCommand" />
```

So i have a CustomEdit that is different from EditText by overriding two events

```
    this.KeyPress += OnEnterKeyPressed;
    this.FocusChange += OnFocusChange;
```

My problem is that Click command is triggered only second time i click on the EditText. First time it just gets focused then then i click it the second time the Click command triggers. I guess it's how it should work, but i would like to catch the first click it's done on the EditText. An other event maybe it is triggered but I could not find a documentation with all the possible binding on EditText. Any ideas how can i catch the first click on an EditText?

Comment: android:focusable="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hankide said, use the Touch event instead.  You will need to create a custom binding.  I happen to have just dealt with this so here it is:

```
public class MvxViewTouchBinding
    : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private readonly View _view;
    private IMvxCommand _command;

    public MvxViewTouchBinding(View view) : base(view)
    {
        _view = view;
        _view.Touch += ViewOnTouch;
    }

    private void ViewOnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        eventArgs.Handled = false;

        if (_command != null)
        {
            _command.Execute();
        }
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        _command = (IMvxCommand)value;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            _view.Touch -= ViewOnTouch;
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(IMvxCommand); }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }
}
```

and in your Setup.cs put

```
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>("Touch",
                                                  view => new MvxViewTouchBinding(view));
    }
```

Then you can bind to Touch instead of Click.

Comment: I will try it for sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Touch` event instead of `Click` to get the event to fire on the first click. Unfortunately, the behavior you described is normal to Android (even though confusing) and isn't related to MVVMCross.